# How to remove the blank space between two frames tkinter Frames

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

```
 self.TCFrameLeftSideFrame = Frame(self.master,width=50, height=100, relief="raise")
    self.TCFrameLeftSideFrame['borderwidth'] = 5
    self.TCFrameLeftSideFrame.pack(side=LEFT)



    self.TestCaseProgressFrame = Frame(self.master,width=50, height=100, relief="raise")
    self.TestCaseProgressFrame['borderwidth'] = 5
    self.TestCaseProgressFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)
    # self.TestCaseProgressFrame.grid(row=1, column=2)

    self.ButtomFrame = Frame(self.master,width=100, height=50, relief="raise")
    self.ButtomFrame['borderwidth'] = 1
    self.ButtomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

I have three frames left ,right and bottom using tkinter Frame.
Each frames i have added components like button and labels.

The problem is there is blank space between the frames .I highlighted question mark symbol
how to remove the space in this GUI? pls give suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant code. It's always best to provide a [mre] - remember: we can't help you if we don't know what you've tried!

Comment: Probably adding `fill='y'` (or `fill='both'`) and `expand=True` when packing the right frame will do it, but you haven't provided enough code for us to run.

Comment: You need to pack the bottom frame first, then the left and right frames.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough of your code snippet for me to quickly remake it but you can adjust the spacing of your buttons by using the .grid(). .grid() will let you control placement of frames and then elements within the frames as well. If you don't specify a padx argument when you call .grid(), the default is 0 and will place your elements (in this case frame) side by side as long nothing else in the column/row disrupts the placement. I'm include a link that can better explain if you would like to learn more.

```
self.TCFrameLeftSideFrame = Frame(self.master,width=50, height=100, relief="raise")
    self.TCFrameLeftSideFrame['borderwidth'] = 5
    self.TCFrameLeftSideFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)



    self.TestCaseProgressFrame = Frame(self.master,width=50, height=100, relief="raise")
    self.TestCaseProgressFrame['borderwidth'] = 5
    self.TestCaseProgressFrame.grid(row=0, column=1)
   

    self.ButtomFrame = Frame(self.master,width=100, height=50, relief="raise")
    self.ButtomFrame['borderwidth'] = 1
    self.ButtomFrame.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-grid-method-in-tkinter/

Answer (score -1):

Use the place() function to place it in the right side and pack in it .
Then measure the width and lenght and provide an argument for the the geometry of the window your going to be needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).